# List of rails build in handy methods data: { disable_with: 'Working...', confirm: 'XXX' }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I can't find documentation  for a feature of rails - when you create a link_to or etc. you can pass these  params and ujs would take there... but i can't find a list of these methods for rails 3.X. could you help me or give me an insight on where to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for UJS functionality for specific helpers... I highly recommend using API Dock. I get a lot of extra mileage out of the comments there. For example, look up `link_to` and check out the comments for extra info. Then, look up `button_tag`, which is where the `disable_with` data attribute is listed.

But, ultimately, it sounds like what you're looking for is a list of what all UJS hooks rails has. This Rails Guide will help: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html -- and it should also point you to the `rails.js` file that gets the work done: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js.